# Getting a file from directory

Tags: c#

I have to develop a service in which my 1st task is

->CSV files get put into a directory

directory is in the form of \servername\DirectoryName\.csv.

can any one help me out how to do this because I am a absolute beginner in programming.

Comment: Take a look at System.IO.File http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file_methods.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code

```
string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
string dir = fileInfo.DirectoryName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Directory.GetFiles method`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hwtke0f.aspx

```
var targetDirectory = "...";
var files = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see one of these on how to create a Windows Service using C#:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C

Then, you can have a look at [How to: Copy, Delete, and Move Files and Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx)

I hope this helps!